# How to save as excel file with yesterdays date in new file name using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write the code using vba where the Excel macro would run and the file would be saved afterwards in the remote location with yesterday's date. But i am not sure how i can add yesterday's date in file name. Kindly help.

```vb
'Input Excel File's Full Path
  ExcelFilePath = "C:\Abc.xls"

'Input Module/Macro name within the Excel File
  MacroPath = "Module.MacroName"

'Create an instance of Excel
  Set ExcelApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

'Do you want this Excel instance to be visible?
  ExcelApp.Visible = "True"  or "False"

'Prevent any App Launch Alerts (ie Update External Links)
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False

'Open Excel File
  Set wb = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(ExcelFilePath)

'Execute Macro Code
  ExcelApp.Run MacroPath

'Save Excel File (if applicable)
  wb.SaveAs ("\\\XYZ\123\Abc.xls")
  

'Reset Display Alerts Before Closing
  ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = True

'Close Excel File
  wb.Close

'End instance of Excel
  ExcelApp.Quit

'Leaves an onscreen message!
  MsgBox "Your Automated Task successfully ran at " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation
```

Comment: You could use e.g. `wb.SaveAs "\\\XYZ\123\Abc" & Format(Date - 1, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xls"`. `ExcelApp.Visible = True` without the quotes. When done testing, just out-comment it (the default value is `False`) so it is still there if you need further testing. I would use `wb.Close False` for additional 'safety',

Comment: i have tried the solution. getting "Type mismatch : Format" error.

I have tried below as i have the date in K3 cell as well but no luck

wb.SaveAs ("\\\XYZ\123\Abc" & _Format(Range("K3"), "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xls")

Comment: Visual Studio Code

Comment: You need to remove the outer parentheses, it doesn't belong here. Is the value in `K3` a date? You can check with `Debug.Print IsDate(Range("K3"))`. You also need to specify the worksheet for the range e.g. `wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K3").Value`. What's with the underscore (`_`)? That can't work; hopefully, it's a typo. It not, then include it with `"...Abc_"`.

Comment: could you please give me the solution in wb.Saveas query so it would be much better for me.

Comment: `wb.SaveAs "\\\XYZ\123\Abc_" & Format(wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("K3").Value, "yyyy-mm-dd") & ".xls"`. That's one line and there is a space after `...Value,`. Adjust the worksheet name.

Answer (score 0):

Excel handles dates more or less as numbers, where an entire day corresponds with the number 1.

This very simple example gives you an idea how to generate the date from yesterday:

```
Sub Test()
Range("H10").Value = Now()
Range("H11").Value = Now() - 1

End Sub
```